# Move C# Object without Unity Engine over time

Tags: c#, object

Is there a way to move an Object from Point A to point B?

So I am trying create function that will move said object to a to a new position over a duration.

```
public void MoveEntity(NetHandle nethandle, Vector3 current, Vector3 target, int duration)
    {
   // Not sure how to build this out...

    }
```

The NetHandle is the object and I am trying to move it from it's current Vector3 position to the Target Vector3 position over a time span. So say from Point A to Point B over 5 seconds. I can't figure out where to even start, I am not using UnityEngine so I can not use transform. Everything on the internet talks about using transform but I do not have that available, can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: It’s called interpolation. That should find lots of information with your favorite search engine

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by "move an Object ...  in visual studio?" - unless you're writing an extension for the Visual Studio code editor? Assuming you're writing code for some kind of game, you probably want to write a method which you call once per frame, and pass a time step into.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to move game object from point A to B.

Comment: I'd recommend adding more details *to your question* (by editing) if you can. For example: is it a game? If it's a game, are you doing this from your render loop / render loop update method?

Comment: You need to track time, so you need to add a timer if you do not already have one. Then whenever the timer ticks you calculate the new position by interpolation between the start and end based on the elapsed time. Once it reaches the end point you stop tracking the item on timer ticks.

Comment: @PhilWright Could you show me, or answer with a small example? using the function params above?

Comment: No, it is too big. You cannot do it all in that one method. You need external time but timer tick processing. Plus a list of outstanding objects that need moving that can be updated each tick.